# How to pass data[] from thread to Activity

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want to send continuously generated data[] **from** CalcThread which was created in MainActivity **to** GraphActivitity which was created in MainActivity too.

I'd like to use Handler technology to send multiply messages to Activity object. Hope it is possible. I've checked whole bunch of proposals and found. They are: single transmission or not using Handler or adding third-part components about. As I understand using Messages and Handlers is convenient, safe and easy technology. But it seems to me already not too easy, alas.

```
In MainActivity:
//Start calculation thread
public void readStart(View v) {
    audioRecorder = new AudioReceiver(myAudioFormat);
    tAudioReceiverThread = new Thread(audioRecorder);
    tAudioReceiverThread.start();
}
//Start Graph Activity
public void openGraph(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GraphActivity.class);
    Handler hh = new Handler();
    audioRecorder.addHandler(hh);
    intent.putExtra("fff", (Parcelable) hh);//my fantasy
    startActivity(intent);
}

In AudioReceiver class:
public class AudioReceiver implements Runnable {

private List<Handler> handlers;
private AudioRecord mRecord;

public void addHandler(Handler handler)
    {
    handlers.add(handler);
    }

private void sendMsg(short[] data)
{   for(Handler handler : handlers)
    {
        handler.sendMessage(handler.obtainMessage(1, data));
    }}

In GraphActivity:
I have to get handler and register listener. Not sure.
```

My question is. How to register handler in list and transmit it to GraphActivity? I think i don't understand technology. So may somebody explain what i skipped in school, please. Thank you.

Comment: use parcelable concepts.The parcelable objects are able to pass via intent in android

Comment: Thank you. Yes, OpenGraph function have to be like this.                          public void openGraph(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GraphActivity.class);
        Handler hh = new Handler();
        audioRecorder.addHandler(hh);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putParcelable("hh",(Parcelable)hh);
        startActivity(intent,bundle);
    }

Answer (score 0):

OpenGraph function have to be like this. `public void openGraph(View v) { Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GraphActivity.class); Handler hh = new Handler(); audioRecorder.addHandler(hh); Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); bundle.putParcelable("hh",(Parcelable)hh); startActivity(intent,bundle); }`